# RCU in C++11 using std::shared_ptr and a little more

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, concurrency

Here's some code I wrote to solve a problem at the server I'm working on. Is this valid? I've tested it, and it works, but I would like some opinions on this.

It's basically a singly_lock_free_linked_list based on the RCU concept.

```
class data_list
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION update;
    std::atomic_int64_t count;
    concurrency::concurrent_queue<std::shared_ptr<data>> to_add;
    concurrency::concurrent_queue<int> to_remove;

public:
    data_list() :head(nullptr), count(0) { InitializeCriticalSection(&update); }
    ~data_list() {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&update);

        std::shared_ptr<node> cursor = head;
        head = nullptr;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!cursor) break;
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }

    struct node { std::shared_ptr<data> d; std::shared_ptr<node> next; };
    std::shared_ptr<node> head;
```

```
    int push_front(std::shared_ptr<data> d)
    {
        to_add.push(std::move(d));
        if (!TryEnterCriticalSection(&update))
            return 0;

        int a = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!to_add.try_pop(d)) break;

            std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::make_shared<node>();
            temp->d = d;
            temp->next = head;
            while (1) { if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head, &head, temp)) break; }

            a++;
            count++;
        }
        LeaveCriticalSection(&update);
        return a;
    }
```

```
    void remove(int uid)
    {
        to_remove.push(uid);
        if (!TryEnterCriticalSection(&update))
            return;

        std::shared_ptr<node> back;
        std::shared_ptr<node> front;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!to_remove.try_pop(uid)) break;

            back = nullptr;
            front = head;
            while (1)
            {
                if (!front) break;

                if (front->d->uid == uid) {

                    if (back)
                    {
                        back->next = front->next;
                        while (1) { if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&back->next, &back->next, front->next))break; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        while (1) { if (std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&head, &head, front->next))break; }
                    }

                    count--;
                    break;
                }

                back = front;
                front = front->next;
            }

        }

        LeaveCriticalSection(&update);
    }
```

```
    std::shared_ptr<data> get(int uid) const
    {
        std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::atomic_load(&head);

        while (1)
        {
            if (!temp)break;

            if (temp->d->uid == uid)
                return temp->d;

            temp = std::atomic_load(&temp->next);
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
```

```
    void collect(int v, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<data>> & out_collection) const
    {
        std::shared_ptr<node> temp = std::atomic_load(&head);

        while (1)
        {
            if (!temp)break;

            if (temp->d->b == v)
                out_collection.push_back(temp->d);
            temp = std::atomic_load(&temp->next);
        }
    }
```

```
    int64_t get_count() const
    {
        return count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
};
```

Comment: there is a "bug" for this.

Comment: What does your comment mean? A bug for what? Does your code have a bug?

Comment: yeah..not a bug...more like an inconvenience. So, when you push_back an item you try to lock if  you can't , you push your item into the to_add queue which is supposed to be empty by the thread that got the lock before you, but if you push your item into the queue right when the other queue is about to unlock, your items remains inside the to_add queue and are added when next thread wants to push_back new item....it can be solved.

Comment: I found a solution for the problem, i'll post the new code.